# Desktop Environment not working - Black screen, no mouse

Tags: kubuntu

I had been upgrading my Kubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10, when it crashed.
When I booted up again I only have the black screen and my mouse.

OS: (k)Ubuntu 17.04(?)
Computer: Acer Aspire V5
HELP!

Comment: It crashed during which part of the upgrade? Downloading? Or installing? The answer is important.

Comment: it crashed during Installing

Answer (score 1):

A crash or poweroff during the install part of a release upgrade is the time when your system is *most vulnerable*. The mix of old and new packages are incompatible, and can leave your system broken in a wide range from completely unbootable to fiddly little annoyances.

If you are expert, you can sometimes use clever tools (like a chroot) to complete the upgrade. However, for most users, repair is too complex or otherwise simply not worthwhile.

**For most users**: Create a LiveUSB using a different machine, then backup your data, then reinstall fresh.